# How to notify a single listener on every failed Httprequest with Retrofit on Android

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to connect my app to a webbackend. We use the asynchronous callback methods to do requests at different points in the app.

How would I add a listener that is notified every time a http-request fails.

My current idea is to create a custom callback class that all callbacks in my app must extend. This callback will inform my listener on every failure.

If I change all Interface to only except subtypes of this class and make the failure and success method final - with a callback to an abstract method - it should not be possible to miss a call in the whole application.

Is there a simpler way then this?

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach to do this is using a callback, but you can also send an event to your activity using any event framework or using a local event broadcast such as:

- to send the event you have to use something like:

  ```
      private void sendMessage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("event-networkerror");
        intent.putExtra("message", "data");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
      }
  ```
- To subscribe to the event:

  ```
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("event-networkerror"));
      }

      // handler for received Intents for the "my-event" event 
      private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // Extract data included in the Intent
          String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
          Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
        }
      };

      protected void onPause() {
        // Unregister since the activity is not visible
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        super.onPause();
      }
  ```

You can use the ErrorHandler to send the broadcast:

```
        class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
          public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
            Response r = cause.getResponse();
            // process error r.getStatus()
            Intent intent = new Intent("event-networkerror");
            intent.putExtra("status",r.getStatus());
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            return cause;
          }
        }

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("...")
        .setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler())
        .build();
```

Comment: And how do I plug in this mechanism into the retrofit http library?

Comment: I've edited the awnser, I'm using retrofit+robospice, but I guess you could use the retrofit ErrorHandler

Comment: The error handler is only used in synchronous calls. In calls with a callback the ErrorHandler is not used as it seems.